# chromedriver mystery: Why does cdriver stick on data:,

Tags: capybara, selenium-chromedriver

It is a conundrum, yesterday my chromedriver automation worked as usual.

Today, it pulls up the cromebrowser, and remains blankscreened, with

```
data:,
```

as the URL.

This used to happen with capy/chrome but the URL was

about:blank

Why would this stop working all of a sudden?  Is this happening to anyone else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we believe happened is that something we did on our system didn't sit with the old version of chromedriver we were using.

Changing to v2.8.241036 fixed the issue.

Comment: Yes it is happening to me but I'm already using chromedriver v2.10. :S